# Insert a record into database and associate it to a record in another table without the id

Tags: sql, postgresql

This may be a duplicate question, but I do not know the terminology to use to search for the answer.

I have an `account` table with the following fields:

- id
- email

And a `widget` table with the following field:

- id
- name
- account_id

The `account_id` is set as foreign key and it references the account(id).

How do I insert a widget and associate it to an existing account record in a single query if only the account `email` is known?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `account.id` is an  `identity` (or `serial`) column, you can use a [writetable CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
with new_account as (
  insert into account (email) values ('....')
  returning id
)
insert into widget (name, account_id)
select id, 'new widget'
from new_account;
```

Comment: @user1135541: I was wrong. using `lasval()` won't work properly if `widget` also has an `identity` column